# Preg_match_all with nested matches

Tags: regex, templates, multidimensional-array, nested, preg-match-all

i'm developing a template system and running into some issues.

The plan is to create HTML documents with [@tags] in them.
I could just use str_replace (i can loop trough all posible replacements), but i want to push this a little further ;-)

I want to allow nested tags, and allow parameters with each tag:

```
[@title|You are looking at article [@articlenumber] [@articlename]]
```

I would like to get the following results with preg_match_all:

```
[0] title|You are looking at article [@articlenumber] [@articlename]
[1] articlenumber
[2] articlename
```

My script will split the | for parameters.
The output from my script will be something like:

```
<div class='myTitle'>You are looking at article 001 MyProduct</div>
```

The problem i'm having is that i'm not exprerienced with regex. Al my paterns results almost what i want, but have problems with the nested params.

```
\[@(.*?)\]
```

Will stop at the ] from articlenumber.

```
\[@(.*?)(((?R)|.)*?)\]
```

Is more like it, but it doesn't catch the articlenumber; https://regex101.com/r/UvH7zi/1

Hope someone can help me out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe it's time to use a proper html parser, like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ ;) Here is a summary on pcre recursive patterns, but that'll come out of hand very quickly http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using general Python regular expressions. You are looking for a feature similar to "[balancing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html)" available in the .[NET RegEx's engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing_group_definition) that allows nested matches.

Take a look at [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Documentation) that allows nested expression:
from pyparsing import nestedExpr

```
import pyparsing as pp
text = '{They {mean to {win}} Wimbledon}'
print(pp.nestedExpr(opener='{', closer='}').parseString(text))
```

The output is:

```
[['They', ['mean', 'to', ['win']], 'Wimbledon']]
```

Unfortunately, this does not work very well with your example. You need a better grammar, I think.

You can experiment with a QuotedString definition, but still.

```
import pyparsing as pp
single_value = pp.QuotedString(quoteChar="'", endQuoteChar="'")
parser = pp.nestedExpr(opener="[", closer="]",
                       content=single_value,
                       ignoreExpr=None)

example = "['@title|You are looking at article' ['@articlenumber'] ['@articlename']]"
print(parser.parseString(example, parseAll=True))
```

Comment: The closest thing to your desired output using your original pattern I could find was this:  
 `\[@(.*?)(\b((?R)|.)*?)*\]`

Comment: wp78de: this is the closest to what i've ment. The issue is when nest another tag inside the title, it isn't found because the number of parameters are not dynamic. But your awnser was extremely close to what i needed

Comment: And i'm sorry for not mention my program language, i use PHP.
For now i've crated a parser:

`- get all opening tags, and put their strpos in array
- loop trough all start positions of the opening tags
- Look for the next closingtag, is it before the next open-tag? than the tag is complete
- If the closingtag was after an opening tag, skip that one and look for the next (and keep checking for openingtags in between)`

That way i could find all complete tags and replace them.
But that took about 50 lines of code and multiple loops, so one preg_match would be greater ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm typing this on my phone so there might be some mistakes, but what you want can be quite easily achieved by incorporating a lookahead into your expression:

```
(?=\\[(@(?:\\[(?1)\\]|.)*)\\])
```

Edit: Yup, it works, here you go: https://regex101.com/r/UvH7zi/4

Because (?=) consumes no characters, the pattern looks for and captures the contents of all "[@*]" substrings in the subject, recursively checking that the contents themselves contain balanced groups, if any.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code:

```
@\w+\|[\w\s]+\[@(\w+)]\s+\[@(\w+)]
```

https://regex101.com/r/UvH7zi/3

Answer (score 0):

For now i've crated a parser:

`- get all opening tags, and put their strpos in array
- loop trough all start positions of the opening tags
- Look for the next closingtag, is it before the next open-tag? than the tag is complete
- If the closingtag was after an opening tag, skip that one and look for the next (and keep checking for openingtags in between)`

That way i could find all complete tags and replace them.
But that took about 50 lines of code and multiple loops, so one preg_match would be greater ;-)